# Get full height of a clipped DIV

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the height of the div which includes the clipped area of the div ?

```
<div style="height: 20px; overflow: hidden">
  content<br>content<br>content<br>
  content<br>content<br>content<br>
  content<br>content<br>content<br>
</div>
```

Comment: for anyone looking for the better approach skip the accepted answer and try the @Colt answer.

Comment: Except that answer uses jQuery, and this question did not ask anything about jQuery.

Comment: I think the point was in the use of `scrollHeight`... not the *jQuery*

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, you cannot do it that way, but it's possible when adding a  inner element to your container, like this:

```
<div id="element" style="height: 20px; overflow: hidden;">
    <p id="innerElement"> <!-- notice this inner element -->
        content<br />content<br />content<br />
        content<br />content<br />content<br />
        content<br />content<br />content<br />
    </p>
</div>
```

*sidenote:* wrapping content inside paragraphs is a good practice too, plus that one extra element isn't giving that much of problems, if any at all...

And JavaScript:

```
var innerHeight = document.getElementById('innerElement').offsetHeight;
alert(innerHeight);
```

P.S. For this JavaScript to work, put it after your `#element` div, because plain JavaScript is executed before DOM is ready if it's not instructed to do so. To make this work when DOM is ready, [check this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml).

But I'd suggest getting [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it will come in handy later on if you're going to extend JavaScript operations in your site.

Plus, jQuery is **the power**, for real!

That way, simply add this script to your `<head />` (assuming you've jQuery included):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var innerHeight = $('#innerElement').height();
 alert(innerHeight);
});
```

[Example @jsFiddle using jQuery way!](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/Gm3nK/)

Comment: Yep. Looks like this is the best way to do it. Thanks. Oh and yes, I love jQuery. Lovely library.

Comment: Tip: (This just caught me out) if you keep getting 0 returned from height or offsetHeight, make sure that you have set your elements to be visible before you do the measuring.

Comment: It's not necessary to add an inner element, the scrollHeight property contains the height of the element including the clipped area.

Answer (score 51):

This works in all cases, whether you have a text node inside or a container. This is using jquery, but you don't need to.

```
//return the total height.
totalHeight = $('#elem')[0].scrollHeight;
//return the clipped height.
visibleHeight = $('#elem').height();
```

$('#elem')[0] is returning the dom element from the jquery call. so you can use that on any dom elem using plain ol' javascript.

Comment: The trick is in the scrollHeight property here, which contains the height of the element before clipping. The property is available without jQuery.

Comment: Thank you! 
I tried without [0] and got undefined...

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way to achieve what you need, using Fabian idea:

```
function GetHeight() {
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("MyDiv");
    var sOriginalOverflow = oDiv.style.overflow;
    var sOriginalHeight = oDiv.style.height;
    oDiv.style.overflow = "";
    oDiv.style.height = "";
    var height = oDiv.offsetHeight;
    oDiv.style.height = sOriginalHeight;
    oDiv.style.overflow = sOriginalOverflow;
    alert("Real height is " + height);
}
```

Live demo and test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/7Lbz9/

Comment: Yep, this would do. Although was hoping I would not need to remove the overflow before calculate the height.

Comment: Actually, this happens to solve my problem perfectly, as the speed at which the overflow is set/reset does not put in a scroll

Comment: @Prakash as I'm only setting a variable then set the original overflow and height back, it's done within one "tick" of the CPU so user won't see any change in UI.

Answer (score 5):

Use `scrollHeight` of the element instead of `clientHeight` or `offsetHeight`.

Wrapping the content approach is better though.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thats not possible afaik. What you could try is to remove that style and set it using javascript after you got the height. Not the most elegant solution, but i think its the only one.

Comment: I gave flesh and bones to that idea, IMO it's elegant enough when wrapped nicely into a function. :)

Answer (score 0):

Native Javascript. [Supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollHeight) as far back as MSIE 6:

```
<div id="cont" style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:auto;border:#000 solid 1px;">
    <div style="height:1500px;">dddd</div>
</div>


<script>alert(document.getElementById('cont').scrollHeight)</script>
```