# Getting div height

Tags: javascript, html

Firebug tells me the computed style of `my_div`:

width   300px

height  453.167px

Yet when I execute `console.log(mydiv.style.height)`, it gives me an empty string, even though `console.log(mydiv)` logs the correct element. I am sure the page has loaded by the time this logging code is called. I'd appreciate a solution that does not use jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the rendered height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Depending on the browser of choice, one of these will do:

```
mydiv.offsetHeight
mydiv.clientHeight
```

[Get full height of a clipped DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612992/get-height-of-a-div)

[Getting the height of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101230/getting-the-height-of-a-div)

Comment: Thanks! They both work. Do you know why mydiv.style.height doesn't work?

Comment: @RosePerrone `element.style.height` only returns the inline style, which means that if you don't specify the style in the element's tag (i.e `<div style="height:200px"></div>`), the `style` property will return an empty string for any property.

Comment: @rosePerrone `style.height` is just the value of the CSS style property. Since you set no height this is blank.

Comment: Why doesn't the style property return the computed style, rather than returning only the value of CSS rules that the programmer has specified?

Comment: @RosePerrone: Because that's the way the code is written - you could probably find some deep dark corner of the W3C specs that say it, but it is best not to waste your time on minor things like that.

Comment: @josh.trow thanks, I can see how this way of printing CSS rules would be helpful for debugging--the programmer can always inspect an element to get its computed properties, but if she wants to see only the rules she specifies, she can log it.

Answer (score -3):

UPDATE:

Many browser inconsistencies have been fixed since my original answer. Now the `clientHeight` property of a DOM element is reliable.

`var height = element.clientHeight;`

> The Element.clientHeight read-only property is zero for elements with no CSS or inline layout boxes, otherwise it's  the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin.
>
> clientHeight can be calculated as CSS height + CSS padding - height of horizontal scrollbar (if present).
>
> Note: This property will round the value to an integer. If you need a fractional value, use element.getBoundingClientRect().

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight

Original answer:

If you use the jQuery JS library, you can just do this:

```
var computed_height = $('#my_div').height();
```

If you use the Prototype JS library, it's similar:

```
var computed_height = $('my_div').getHeight();
```

Using a library is often the easiest & most cross-browser way to do something. Getting computed styles with vanilla js is unreliable because the properties are different across browsers.

Comment: I'll not vote you down because it is technically valid, but please look and respect the question: `I'd appreciate a solution that does not use jQuery.`

Comment: But it doesn't say it's a requirement. ;) If you'd like I can post some ways with other libraries. Point is vanilla js is janky for stuff like this because of the different properties in different browsers. 

It's easier to call 1 method ".height()" than to say if this browser then it's this property, if this browser then it's this property, etc.

Comment: Oh believe me I too would absolutely use a library, but when the post explicitly asks for non-library methods I find it best to assume they have a reason.