# Detect amount of overflow in React Native View

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to detect the amount (height) of overflowed contents when [`overflow: 'hidden'`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style) is set on a View?

In HTML it's possible to do this by comparing `height` to `scrollHeight` as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5627286/1516199).

I haven't found a way to do this for React Native, and I need to figure out what the overflow height is so that I can perform an animation.